# Adding elements to html body with variable as a text

Tags: javascript, html

I want to create something like this but with javascript:

```
<div>1</div>
<div>2</div>
<div>3</div>
<div>4</div>
```

and so on.
I tried do this:

```
var i = 0;
function tick()
{
  document.body.innerHTML += '<div>i</div>';
  i++;
  setTimeout("tick()",1000);
}
```

but instead of variable value, div elements contain variable name. Is it any way to do this work properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for your problem I think you can use `setInterval()` to do that, and playing with the DOM if you use pure javascript.

Here I give you an example, hope it can help :D

```js
var i = 0;

function hell () {
 i++
 var test = document.createElement("div")
 var node = document.createTextNode(i);
  
  test.appendChild(node)
  document.getElementById("a").appendChild(test);  
}

var interval = setInterval(hell, 1000);

function generateDiv() {
 setTimeout(interval, 10000)
}

function stopGenerate() {
  clearInterval(interval)
}
```

```html
<button onclick="generateDiv()">
  Generate Div :D
</button>
<button onclick="stopGenerate()">
  Stop Generate
</button>
<div id="a">

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to concatenate the value of `i` with the string.

```
document.body.innerHTML += '<div>' + i + '</div>';
//                            ---^^^^^^^^^---
```

```js
var i = 0;

function tick() {
  document.body.innerHTML += '<div>' + i + '</div>';
  i++;
  setTimeout("tick()", 1000);
}
tick();
```

---

The above solution would completely recreate the elements in the body each time, instead generate a dom element and append to the body which keeps the old elements.

```js
var i = 0;

function tick() {
  // create div element
  var div = document.createElement('div');
  //set content
  div.innerHTML = i;
  // append to the body
  document.body.appendChild(div);
  i++;
  setTimeout("tick()", 1000);
}

tick();
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use this

```
var i = 0;
function tick()
{
  document.body.innerHTML += '<div>'+i+'</div>';
  i++;
  setTimeout("tick()",1000); 
}
```

Whatever is inside double quotes is used as it is and the outside it is treated as javascript syntax, i.e. as a variable

Answer (score 0):

You need to break out the value from the string

```
document.body.innerHTML += '<div>'+ i +'</div>';
```

Answer (score 0):

you are using `'<div>i</div>'` which makes 'i' just a character, because it is a string between quotes, you need to concatenate its value between two stings `'<div>'` and `'</div>'`

```
 var i = 0;
    function tick()
    {
      document.body.innerHTML += '<div>' + i + '</div>';
      i++;
      setTimeout("tick()",1000);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You've set the value to the string literal `'<div>i</div>'`. You need to treat i as a variable. `'<div>'+i+'</div>'` should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

**Issues:**

1. Concatenation (without concatenation **i** was considered as a character instead of variable.)
2. function was not called (not sure because you did not post in question)

```js
var i = 1;
function tick()
{
  document.body.innerHTML += '<div>'+i+'</div>';
  i++;
  setTimeout("tick()",1000);
}
tick();
```

```html
<body></body>
```

**NOTE:** Currently, the function is being called without any event but you can trigger it on event like click, load etc.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the variable `i` outside the single quotes like this:

```
document.body.innerHTML += '<div>' + i + '</div>';
```

That way JS will know you want to use it's value and not the text "i".

Also notice that you initiated `i = 0;` which means the first outputted value will be `<div>0</div>`. To make the first value 1 you should either initiate `i = 1;` or increment it's value before outputting the value and not after.